# Assign every two characters to a letter of the alphabet using batch

Tags: string, batch-file, split

I have a randomly generated number made of 52 characters and would like to assign every two characters to a letter in the alphabet

For instance the number generated is:

```
8418883335015492815087755766083114261445499300375638
```

I would like the first two `84` to be assigned to a variable called `VAR_A`, then `18` to `VAR_B` and so on.

How can I best do this?

edit:::

```
set MY_ALPHABET=1234567890

set MY_A=%MY_ALPHABET:~-2%

SET MY_ALPHABET_B = (%MY_ALPHABET% - %MY_A%)

echo %MY_ALPHABET_B%
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and then we can help.

Comment: FYI if this is some kind of cypher both Q & S == 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a silly excercise, but here goes

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set  "chars=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
set "string=8418883335015492815087755766083114261445499300375638"

::Assign variables
for /l %%N in (0 2 50) do set "var_!chars:~%%N,1!=!string:~%%N,2!"

::Show results
set var
```

Result:

```
var_A=84
var_B=18
var_C=88
var_D=33
var_E=35
var_F=01
var_G=54
var_H=92
var_I=81
var_J=50
var_K=87
var_L=75
var_M=57
var_N=66
var_O=08
var_P=31
var_Q=14
var_R=26
var_S=14
var_T=45
var_U=49
var_V=93
var_W=00
var_X=37
var_Y=56
var_Z=38
```

Comment: Its only silly because I havent said what Im trying to achive ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way of doing it but it works

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set start=0
set step=2
set end=52
set nvar=1
set number=8418883335015492815087755766083114261445499300375638
:LOOP
if %start%==%end% (
echo done
pause >nul
) else (
set var%nvar%=!number:~%start%,%step%!
echo !var%nvar%!
set /a start+=2
set /a nvar+=1
goto :LOOP
)
pause >nul
```

When it's finished you will have 26 variables named `var1` up to `var26`.